# Pattern matching on types

Tags: haskell

Is there nice way to write the following "x is of type t" parts? (I suspect I should be using [Data.Type.Equality](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html) but I'm not sure exactly how)

```
f :: a -> Int
g :: b -> Int

h :: Typeable t => t -> Maybe Int
h x = case x of
  (x is of type a) -> Just (f x)
  (x is of type b) -> Just (g x)
  _ -> Nothing
```

[Follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886170/using-typeable-to-effectively-case-match-against-different-types)

Comment: As far as I know, objects have no type at runtime. So once the compiler produced a binary, the types are unknown: one cannot inspect the type nor act accordingly. That is the advantage of a statically typed language.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Note the `Typeable` constraint

Comment: But there's a `Typeable` constraint. So I can do things like `cast` for example yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for the "type safe cast" bits of `Data.Typeable`. [`cast :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Maybe b`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:cast) pulls the runtime type information out of the `Typeable` dictionaries for `a` and `b` and compares them; if `a` and `b` are the same type then it returns `Just` its argument, otherwise it fails.

So, with `cast` and `Maybe`'s `Alternative` instance in hand, we have:

```
h x = f <$> cast x
  <|> g <$> cast x
```

As far as I know, there's no way to avoid the repetitious calls to `cast`, since they occur at different types.

Comment: Ah, that's roughly what I was thinking, but using alternative does make the code prettier.

Comment: Could you look at the follow up question in the edit?

Comment: Probably warrants a separate question, but briefly: you'll have to bring the type equalities into scope by matching [`eqT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:eqT) with `Just Refl` (or `fmap`ping [`gcastWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html#v:gcastWith)). Then inside the block you know `t ~ a` or `t ~ b` and you can apply `f` or `g` as before

Comment: I've made a separate question and linked to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886170/using-typeable-to-effectively-case-match-against-different-types