# Using Typeable to effectively case match against different types

Tags: haskell

I roughly want to achieve the following:

```
f :: a -> a
g :: b -> b

h :: Typeable t => t -> Maybe t
h x = case x of
  (x is of type a) -> Just (f x)
  (x is of type b) -> Just (g x)
  _ -> Nothing
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's code for the idea I outlined in [my earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885661/pattern-matching-on-types/44885878?noredirect=1#comment76750186_44885878). You need `ScopedTypeVariables` to tell the elaborator at which type to call `eqT`.

```
infixl 4 <?>
(<?>) :: forall a b. (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (a -> a) -> b -> Maybe b
f <?> x = fmap (\Refl -> f x) (eqT :: Maybe (a :~: b))

h :: Typeable t => t -> Maybe t
h x = f <?> x
  <|> g <?> x
```

Probably warrants some explanation. `f <?> x` attempts to apply `f` to `x`, if its type matches. [`eqT :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => Maybe (a :~: b)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:eqT) tests the two `Typeable` dictionaries to see if `a` and `b` are the same type. If they are, it returns `Just Refl`, a GADT proof that they are the same type. Pattern matching on `Refl`, as I did in the lambda, brings that equality into scope. In the body of the lambda GHC knows `a ~ b`, so we can safely apply `f` to `x`.

Comment: Perhaps useful to note that you can also write a version of `<?>` with the stronger type `(Typeable a, Typeable b) => (a -> a) -> Maybe (b -> b)`; at this type, `<?>` is simply `cast`.

Comment: @user2407038 Oh, of course! I didn't even think of that. Then the `<?>` in my answer is `sequenceA . cast`. Nice!